# "Mock location app" appear in the list but can't be selected

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, gps, location

I can't understand why the app i'm working on **appears** in the "mock location app" list under Developer settings, but if i select it nothing happens, it's still off...
I've searched everywhere but can't find a solution, every question i've read here is related to the app **not appearing** in the list.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Boolean:

```
private boolean hasMockLocationPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    true, true, false, false,
                    true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_HIGH, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return (Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 0) != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still can't figure it out, the app can be "clicked" but the field doesn't change

Comment: Did you solved it? I have same problem...the app can be clicked but not selected.

Comment: No... gave up and i don't work anymore on that project